# Git fails to merge in a simple case but running my merge tool reveals no conflicts

Tags: git, version-control, merge, versioning

Git fails to merge in a simple case but running my merge tool reveals no conflicts and just closing the merge tool results in the correct merge results.

I'm using git version 1.7.10.msysgit.1 and I have this strange issue with merging.

I have a file containing "123"
then Branch A and Branch B are both spawned off of the above version of the file.

On branch B i add "new line" to line 2 of the file to get
"123
new line"

On branch B i then change "123" to "12345"

On branch A i cherry pick the change off of B which added the "new line"

On branch A i merge with B and I get a conflict on "123" "12345" when i open the file in a text editor but if i launch my merge tool, change nothing and close it, the conflict is auto resolved and i can continue.

What i'm wondering is why does git think that there is a conflict on the first line of the file when nobody has touched the first line on branch A.

Is there a way to get git to auto merge in these situations and not bother me?

Answer (score 0):

Its because you cherry-picked the change from B into A.  This essentially "copied" the commit that modified the line.  Now, you have the same line modified by two different commits AFTER the common ancestor of the two branches.  So, git cannot know which commit is the correct one that you want, so it signals a conflict to let you pick.

Comment: nobody modified the first line of the file except on B and the cherry picked commit modified line 2 with the identical change.  I was hoping git was smart enough to realize that if the same change is already being applied it wouldn't complain, and it seems like it doesn't.  It has a problem with line one which WAS NOT cherry picked and only branch B changed it.  This is what is confusing.

Comment: This is further proven if i merge with the first commit on B (the one i cherry picked previously) git does the merge by recursive strategy and doesn't get any conflicts.  It really conflicts on line one which there should be no way for it to conflict because line one was only modified on branch B.  Very strange.

Comment: further testing reveals that merging from B the commit that i cherry-picked results in no conflicts and merges automatically fine, then merging again with branch B which only contains the one other commit which modifies line one also resolves automatically.  So git seems to know what to do but why can't it result in no merge conflicts when i don't do the intermediate step of merging with the cherry picked change off of B?  Is there any way to get the same behaviour with no conflicts by just doing one merge with branch B instead of two?